# Reference for Cohomology of Finite Groups

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

There are many books on Cohomology theory of finite groups.

My aim is study this subject thoroughly through a small book/notes, which includes

> self contained introduction to main concepts of cohomology theory of finite groups, and theory of Schur multiplier, with *important* examples

What I don't want is

> Fat, very expository, very basic books/notes on above topics

Actually I want to learn the subject as well as teach it simultaneously to undergraduates, by weekly 2-3 lectures on 1 hour each.

I am avoiding fat, very basic books/notes because (i) I want to stress on main concepts and covering them in limited period, and (ii) through big books/notes, it becomes difficult to select chapters since I am not familiar with this subject.

Can one suggest some good, highly recommended material for this?